# For every $n$, there exists a polynomial of degree $n$ with Galois Group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to prove that one can always construct an nth degree polynomial with Galois Group $S_n.$ I've proven that one can always construct an nth degree polynomial with Galois Group Sn over the field $F_0(s_1,...,s_n)$ where $s_1,...,s_n$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials. I've also seen conditions which a polynomial must have to have Galois Group $S_n,$ but this doesn't prove existence. Does anyone have a proof that there is at least one $n^{th}$ degree polynomial with Galois Group $S_n?$

Thanks

EDIT: I am considering only polynomials over Q (rationals), not other fields in general.

Answer (score 4):

Hilbert showed that all symmetric and alternating groups can be realized as Galois groups of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

A modern exposition of his argument is given in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem) on the Inverse Galois problem, see the section *Symmetric and Alternating Groups*.

Comment: This is interesting, but I would like to prove it without using already known theorems and lemnas which I can't prove myself. I would rather have a proof 'from scratch' if you see what I am getting at

Comment: Could you please explain how on the wikipedia page they are able to claim that Gal(f(x, s)/Q(s)) is doubly transitive?